# How can I 'pad out' a dataframe so all groups are the same length?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on an ML project, of which a simplified (olympic inspired!) illustration is below:

The data is the results of races:

```
race_data = {'Race': {1: '1', 2: '1', 3: '1', 4: '2', 5: '2', 6: '2', 7: '3', 8: '3', 9: '4', 10: '4', 11: '5', 12: '5'}, 
             'Lane' : {1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3', 4: '1', 5: '2', 6: '3', 7: '1', 8: '2', 9: '1', 10: '2', 11: '1', 12: '2'},
             'Name': {1: 'A Rider', 2: 'Dot P', 3: 'S King', 4: 'A Rider', 5: 'S King', 6: 'Roy R', 7: 'Dot P', 8: 'A Rider', 9: 'S King', 10: 'A Rider', 11: ' S King', 12: 'Roy R'}, 
             'InForm': {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 2, 5: 1, 6: 4, 7: 3, 8: 2, 9: 4, 10: 2, 11: 1, 12: 1}, 
             'QRating': {1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 2, 5: 1, 6: 3, 7: 3, 8: 2, 9: 1, 10: 2, 11: 4, 12: 1},
             'Place' : {1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 1, 6: 3, 7: 1, 8: 2, 9: 2, 10: 1, 11: 2, 12: 1}
             }
df = pd.DataFrame(race_data)
```

```
   Race Lane     Name  InForm  QRating  Place
1     1    1  A Rider       1        1      1
2     1    2    Dot P       2        3      3
3     1    3   S King       3        3      2
4     2    1  A Rider       2        2      2
5     2    2   S King       1        1      1
6     2    3    Roy R       4        3      3
7     3    1    Dot P       3        3      1
8     3    2  A Rider       2        2      2
9     4    1   S King       4        1      2
10    4    2  A Rider       2        2      1
11    5    1   S King       1        4      2
12    5    2    Roy R       1        1      1
```

To run each race as a whole I am rolling the features out into a wider form so each 'Lane' has its respective feature set:

```
wide_df = df.pivot(index='Race', columns='Lane', values=df.columns[3:])
wide_df.columns =["Lane"+str(s2)+"-"+ s1 for (s1,s2) in wide_df.columns.tolist()]
```

|  | Lane1-InForm | Lane2-InForm | Lane3-InForm | Lane1-QRating | Lane2-QRating | Lane3-QRating | Lane1-Place | Lane2-Place | Lane3-Place |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.0 | 2.0 | 3.0 | 1.0 | 3.0 | 3.0 | 1.0 | 3.0 | 2.0 |
| 2 | 2.0 | 1.0 | 4.0 | 2.0 | 1.0 | 3.0 | 2.0 | 1.0 | 3.0 |
| 3 | 3.0 | 2.0 | NaN | 3.0 | 2.0 | NaN | 1.0 | 2.0 | NaN |
| 4 | 4.0 | 2.0 | NaN | 1.0 | 2.0 | NaN | 2.0 | 1.0 | NaN |
| 5 | 1.0 | 1.0 | NaN | 4.0 | 1.0 | NaN | 2.0 | 1.0 | NaN |

Races with less than the maximum number of racers are NaN filled, but I fear a problem will come from the fact that the 'NaN' values will always appear in the higher lanes.

Does anyone know of a good way to - perhaps - use Groupby on the original data to 'pad out' all groups to the same length (then I can randomly re-arrange them) or alternatively maybe, to randomly sort the columns by 'Lane' prefix in the pivot table? Or something else altogether?

It would need to scale to 1000s of training/test examples and 10s of race entrants per race.

Comment: What do you want to pad the groups with? I’m not sure what your issue is tbh, why are `NaN`s not an acceptable representation of the fact there are less racers in the last race?

Comment: Sorry - may not have been clear on this. Having the NaNs isn't the problem, my fear is that by having them always associated with the higher numbered 'Lanes' it will skew learning performance. I am looking for a way to distribute them more evenly across the Lanes

Comment: As to what to pad with - they can be padded with NaNs quite happily (but the 'Lane' will need to be a real number incrementing up to the 'max number of lanes in any race in the dataset' (3 in this example) for the pivot to work in its current form

Comment: @BearEHiker Did you find a way to pad. I am also facing a similar kind of issue.